# ggplot2 : create a faceted pie chart with an empty space after the first column

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

At the moment I'm creating a graph like this with the following code ussing ggplot2

```
ggplot(data.df[sel,], aes(x=1, y = mean_ponderation_norm, fill = Usage)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",color='black') +
  coord_polar(theta='y')+
  scale_fill_brewer(type="qual", palette = 2, direction = 1, name="")+
  facet_grid(zone.x~Type_service)+
  theme(#panel.grid = element_blank(), ## remove guide lines
    #axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(),  # the axis ticks
    axis.title=element_blank()  # the axis labels
  )+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))
```

[image: pie chart 1]

But I would like the slices in the second column to start where they stop in the first column. To get something like this

[image: pie chart 2]

Answer (score 2):

When drawing with polar co-ordinates, it's always useful to think about how the desired effect would look in Cartesian co-ordinates. What you are looking for would look something like this in Cartesian coordinates:

[image]

This particular effect is just about possible with a stacked bar chart and a bit of hacking, provided you only have two facets as your picture suggests. However, your code suggests you have 4 or more, so this isn't going to work.

Rather than using a stacked bar, you can achieve the result you're looking for with `geom_rect`. It's a bit disappointing that you didn't supply any data or a minimal reproducible example, since you'll need to transform your own data to be able to use `geom_rect`. I have had to create my own data to show how this can be done, and that means that you will have to figure out how to transform your own data to do the same thing.

Anyway, here's the data I'm going to use. In your data, `mean_ponderation_norm` contains the y values. I'm going to call mine `all_widths`. You need to `cumsum` and normalise this. You also need to create a lagged copy of it with a zero at position 1 and add this to your data frame:

```
set.seed(69)
all_widths <- runif(10, 5, 10)
all_widths <- 60 * cumsum(all_widths)/sum(all_widths)

df <- data.frame(facet_var = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5),
                 factor_var = rep(LETTERS[1:10]),
                 start_var = c(0, all_widths[-length(all_widths)]),
                 end_var  = all_widths)
```

Now your plot goes like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = start_var, 
               ymax = end_var, fill = factor_var)) +
  geom_rect(color = 'black', size = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  facet_grid(. ~ facet_var) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! it work for one facet, but with 2 facet_variable ? `df <- data.frame(facet_var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5),
                 facet_var2 = rep(LETTERS[3:4], each = 5),
                 factor_var = rep(LETTERS[1:10]),
                 start_var = c(0, all_widths[-length(all_widths)]),
                 end_var  = all_widths)`